# Extract float from 'for loop', write to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, append, group-by

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Currently able to group by nth day group.nth(n), and use for loop to generate list of results.

Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [173]:  data
Out [173]:
Date          A                   
1998-04-01   0.005826374
1998-04-02   0.01004055
1998-04-03   0.002867521
....
2001-04-06  -0.006290507
2001-04-07  -0.006330328
2001-04-08  -0.005019305

In [174]:  grouped = data.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month])
Out [174]: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy objectat0x000000002006B828>

In [175]: for x in xrange(1,21):
                 x = x +1
                 g = grouped.nth(x).sum()
                 print x +1, ("%1.3f " % g)
Out [175]:

    1 0.465 
    2 0.068 
    3 0.103 
    ....
    19 -0.075 
    20 0.175 
    21 0.017
```

Code above prints list of range 1,21 and associated value of g (sum of each grouped.nth(1,21)).  I just want to place said values with index(1,21) into a dataframe.

Hope that clears my question up.  Thank you once again.

Comment: You should state which library is this, and preferably add a tag to the question. I have no idea what `df` and `pd` means.

Comment: Do you actually want to get the sum for each day (say only from Day1st-21st) in each month...? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thank you, I want the sum for Day1st-21st over complete set of data.  Several years of data, with approximately  21 data points per month.  so take all the nth = 1 and sum, nth =2 and sum...nth=21 and sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add append to a list from `for loop` and then create a `df` from it.

```
out = []
for x in xrange(1,21):
    x = x +1
    g = grouped.nth(x).sum()
    out.append((x +1, ("%1.3f " % g)))

pd.DataFrame(out)
```

`